# Unable to reactivate Google Cloud Storage after billing failure

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I use google cloud storage connected to a google app engine in the same project. Recently, my google cloud storage was disabled after a billing failure with the message below:

```
AccountProblemYour Google account is not currently enabled for this operation.
Please check https://code.google.com/apis/console/#:billing to see if you have a past due balance or if the credit card (or other payment mechanism) on your account is expired. You can find additional information at https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/signup
```

Therefore, I have paid immediately with my other payment method. However, I am still getting the same message from google.

What else should I do to reactivate my google cloud storage?

Comment: Please visit https://support.google.com/code/contact/cloud_platform_billing and enter a billing support request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

#### Issue Description

- Account was deactivated due to an expired credit card.
- Cloud Storage started failing with the message...

  ```
  <Error>
    <Code>AccountProblem</Code>
    <Message>
      Your Google account is not currently enabled for this operation. Please check https://code.google.com/apis/console/#:billing to see if you have a past due balance or if the credit card (or other payment mechanism) on your account is expired. You can find additional information at https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/signup
    </Message>
  </Error>
  ```

  [image: Google cloud storage billing error]
- Within my Cloud Console project, in **Storage** > **Cloud Storage** > **Storage browser**, I had a message like *"You can use Cloud Storage after you enable billing"*, followed by a big **Enable** button.
- I clicked the **Enable** button, it went away and seemed to work, but I got the same error when trying to view files, and after refreshing the **Storage browser** screen, the message was back.

#### Issue Resolution

I resolved the issue by disabling billing for the entire project (not just on the Cloud storage screen), then re-enabling it. Within the project, click **Billing & settings**, then **Disable billing**. Then re-enable.

[image: Google cloud console disable project billing]

Comment: This solution stop all of your servers or services, be careful.